# Change all hrefs to working directory

Tags: php, html, regex, hyperlink

I have to scrape a website and save all pages as HTML and put it entirely on a DVD. I've done this, but now all the links start with a `/`, and that grabs my root directory. I would like to change all `href`s of all files (1500 pages) to `href="./"` so it always grabs the working directory.

I've seen things about `sed` in `bash`, but I didn't quite catch how to dynamically grab all `href`s and change them.

How could I do this in an efficient way?

Comment: How do you scrape the site? If you use `wget` (which is very good for mirroring/scraping, IMO), you can pass the `-k` flag to make links point to local files.

Comment: The `-k` flag doesn't change anything about the hyperlinks. Just tried it. Or does it replace the links AFTER it has downloaded?

Comment: Yes, it replaces the links after it has completed downloading. It will also convert links inside stylesheets, links to images and other media, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, depending on which tool you're using to scrape the site, you could start with checking whether it supports rewriting links. `wget` will let you do exactly this by passing the `-k` option:

```
-k,  --convert-links      make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to
                          local files.
```

I don't think Ugo Méda's suggestion, the [`base` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4), will work, since your URLs are absolute, and the base tag only lets you specify a base for relative URLs:

```
href = uri [CT]
This attribute specifies an absolute URI that acts as the base URI for resolving relative URIs.
```

To rewrite every `href` is tricky, since it's so hard to know you're doing the right thing -- it depends on the structure of the site. Consider the following example:

/foo/bar.html:

```
<a href="/bar/baz.html">baz</a>
```

If you rewrite that per your suggestion, it will be:

```
<a href="./bar/baz.html">baz</a>
```

But that won't work, since the browser will resolve that to `/foo/bar/baz.html`, when the file is really at `[SOME DIR]/bar/baz.html`. In that case, you really want:

```
<a href="../bar/baz.html">baz</a>
```

What I'm trying to say is that the correct (rewritten) URL is always depending on the location of the current file *and* the location of the target file. In summary, I think your best bet is using `wget` or some other tool which supports URL rewriting, or you will need some more advanced program than just `sed`, which lacks the context needed to correctly convert the link.

Comment: The downloading of all files takes awful lot of time. If it is finished and it works, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Is it still running? I'm fascinated to know if it worked, or not... =)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [`base` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base) ?

Comment: Same thing, the part I don't quite comprehend is the `sed` expression that would be used to fix this.

Comment: And please don't link to W3Schools, try a more reputable source of information, such as the W3 itself (***no*** affiliation or connection to W3Schools): http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html, or Mozilla's Developer Network (MDN): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base

Comment: I **totally** agree with you on that, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Oh, no problem! It's just that linking to that particular *resource* occasionally leads to a peer-response... =)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, the regex might not be 100% so test it out on 1 or 2 files and tweak accordingly:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i 's|href="[^"]/|href="./|g' '{}' \;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't change anything in any of my files.